# Java java.sql.SQLException while i try to concat a value into prepared statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oaf

I wanted to add the a varible in the prepareded statement and

```
String Query = "SELECT count(*) count from  apps.fnd_user fu where " 
             + "UPPER(fu.user_name) like 'ADMIN_ ||:1||' ";  

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);  
stmt.setString(1, CompanyName);
```

yet this error is showing . Any Fix for this mistake ..... can i concat using pipes while preparing the statement.

Comment: The exception usually tells you what is wrong with the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't concatenate in SQL. Do it in Java:

```
String sql = "SELECT count(*) count" +
              " FROM apps.fnd_user fu" +
             " WHERE UPPER(fu.user_name) LIKE ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "ADMIN_" + companyName);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Note that:

- Parameter marker is `?`, not `:1`
- Java variable names should start with lowercase letter
- You should use try-with-resources.

If you insist on doing it in SQL, the syntax would be (using [Concatenation Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)):

```
             " WHERE UPPER(fu.user_name) LIKE 'ADMIN_' || ?";
```

Or (using [`CONCAT()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)):

```
             " WHERE UPPER(fu.user_name) LIKE CONCAT('ADMIN_', ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a function in Oracle [CONCAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm), try this :

```
like CONCAT('ADMIN_', ?);
```

When you use `'ADMIN_ ||:1||'` with `setString` it is just an SQL literal as already mentioned by @Andreas in comment, And this is **wrong syntax**.

---

Beside I'm not sure what did you mean by `:1`, I think it should `?` instead.

Comment: Even with `?`, the SQL text `'ADMIN_ ||?||'` is a SQL literal, so `?` is not a parameter marker. `'ADMIN_' || ?` would have been the right way, and `||` is a valid Oracle operator, so `CONCAT()` function is not necessary.

Comment: @Andreas It's still a valid function and valid solution, if not you should not mention it in your answer no?